# Correcting for a collision overlapping too much?

Tags: unity, 2d

I have a TileMap with a TileMapCollider2D and a Sprite with a BoxCollider2D. I'm not using physics at all so I'm correcting for the collision on my own. Here's my attempt:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * this.Speed;
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * this.Speed;
    Vector3 pos = this.transform.position;
    pos.x += h;
    pos.y += v;

    foreach (Tilemap map in this.Maps) {
        TilemapCollider2D mapc = map.GetComponent<TilemapCollider2D>();
        ColliderDistance2D dist = this.boxCollider.Distance(mapc);
        if (dist.isOverlapped && dist.isValid) {
            Debug.DrawLine(dist.pointB, dist.pointA, Color.white);
            Vector2 correction = dist.normal * dist.distance;
            pos += (Vector3)(correction);
        }
    }

    this.transform.position = pos;
}
```

This logic is on the blue square in this gif:

[image: animation of failed collision correction]

According to [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColliderDistance2D.html), `dist.normal * dist.distance` should be exactly the distance and direction required to make the two colliders touch. However you can see that I can push a few pixels into the red walls. When I release the button it takes several frames to back out of the wall. It goes a little haywire too when I go diagonally into the corner.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are doing a hit test with the current position of the object, not the position of the object offset by the input. The simplest solution would be to set the position multiple times, once before doing hit testing and once after each tilemap. The reason it slides out over a few frames is likely due to [input gravity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html).

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * this.Speed;
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * this.Speed;
    Vector3 pos = this.transform.position;
    pos.x += h;
    pos.y += v;

    //add this line or something similar
    this.transform.position = pos;

    foreach (Tilemap map in this.Maps) {
        TilemapCollider2D mapc = map.GetComponent<TilemapCollider2D>();
        ColliderDistance2D dist = this.boxCollider.Distance(mapc);
        if (dist.isOverlapped && dist.isValid) {
            Debug.DrawLine(dist.pointB, dist.pointA, Color.white);
            Vector2 correction = dist.normal * dist.distance;
            pos += (Vector3)(correction);
            //Need it here too
            this.transform.position = pos;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you may need to use [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) instead of setting `transform.position` for the hit testing to work correctly immediately.